# What is this flowering fern-like plant called?

Tags: identification

Here's a photo of the plant. I've tried plant id apps but no luck.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

One possibility for this is [Erodium cicutarium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erodium_cicutarium) or red storksbill; the foliage and rosette habit match [the botanical description](https://www.fs.fed.us/database/feis/plants/forb/erocic/all.html), however the flower in your illustration, while not perfectly clear, seem to indicate a slightly different arrangement of petals, so it is hard to be certain.

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably buy one and edit the question with a better "more zoomed in" pic.